# how to disable 2FAS from Heroku

Tags: heroku

I've accidentally deleted the 2FAS application and unfortunately I didn't backup. I didn't have the recovery codes as well. Guys please help me out with this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [we can't answer customer service questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577). Contact Heroku support. (And be careful when using MFA. This is exactly how it is _supposed_ to behave. Create backup codes, add multiple MFA methods, etc. so you're not locked out if your phone dies.)

Comment: Well I've contacted them but they didn't respond yet